# Face detection in iphone

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.
I have a requirement is that , to find only the face from selected image, and need to crop it from the original image.Is there any face detection api for it in iphone using objective c . If any one know please tell to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect only face from the selected image .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577446/how-to-detect-only-face-from-the-selected-image)

Comment: @sandhya: Posting the question again just because no-one answered your first isn't a good idea. I know this is frowned upon but have you tried using a well-known-search-engine to see if there are any articles on the web that would help you.

Comment: @Lazarus : Yes i posted the same question again , bcz I thought the question is not understandable by everyone.

Comment: @Sandhya, just edit your question rather than reposting.

Comment: @Lazarus: Lazarus actually i am not that much familiar with this thats why i posted again.

Comment: @sandhya: I suggest you read the faq to help you become familiar.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a RESTful web service API if Internet connection is possible. You can checkout http://skybiometry.com/ for free face detection & recognition API.